# I want to check the number of characters in a String method

Tags: java

I want to check that a certain number of characters in a method that inputs and returns string

```
public static String watsonCrick(String dna){
    dna = "ATA";
    int length = dna.length();
    char firstCharacter = dna.charAt(0);
    char secondCharacter = dnaSequence.charAt(1);
    char thirdCharacer = dna.charAt(2);

}
```

This is my code so far but I dont know what to put as my return and I don't know how to call the method from my main method? All I need is to make sure the string "dna" has three characters in it.
The method doesn't return anything as of yet, I really just want to make sure I'm on the right track and this is how I have to restrict the number of characters in my string.
EDIT: Sorry to add one more thing but if I wanted to add a condition to the method, like let's say I already made a boolean method beforehand and wanted to check if the char firstCharacter was true according to the method how would I add it?

Comment: What is the method supposed to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to call the method from my main method?

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    watsonCrick("ATA");
}
```

or if the `watsonCrick` method is in a different class, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OtherClass.watsonCrick("ATA");
}
```

> All I need is to make sure the string "dna" has three characters in it.

You can do this by putting this at the beginning of the `watsonCrick` method:

```
if (dna.length() != 3) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
```

Comment: Thank you!! Calling it worked fine and it crashed as expected when I included a char at int 4 afterwards.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but if I wanted to add a condition for each character how would I do so? Like for example if I previously made a boolean method to determine if something is a DNA base or not, how would I apply the condition?

Comment: @AlexCabo To check the first character you can do `if (myMethod(dna.charAt(0))`

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Assing dna variable in Main method and then write just methodName(Parameters) for calling the method in Main. i.e

```
String dna;
public static void main(String[] args) {
   dna = "ATA";
   watsonCrick(dna);
}
```

And if you need to make sure the string has three characters, use this;

```
public static String watsonCrick(String dna){
    int length = dna.length();
    if(length == 3) {
       return "true";
    } 
    return "false";
}
```

If you want you can change the return type to Boolen. (True or False)